# bootstrap and react, assign .active class on radio buttons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

I have a row of custom radio buttons that change size if they're checked. By default the first is checked and when I click on another button, bootstrap should add the `.active` class, problem is that the class is not beign added because I dropped the jquery bootstrap library. how can I do this in pure javascript? I tried with simple CSS

```css
CSS

    .step {
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: contain;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 2.2rem;
      height: 55px;
      margin-top: 0.2rem;
      margin-bottom: 0.2rem;
      opacity: 0.8;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: relative;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
      transition: 0.4s;
      width: 55px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .step.active {
      opacity: 1;
      position: relative;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000, 0px 0px 10px #fff, 0px 0px 10px #fff;
      transform: scale(1.8);
      z-index: 99;
    }

TRIED

    input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ 
      opacity: 1;
      position: relative;
      text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000, 0px 0px 10px #fff, 0px 0px 10px #fff;
      transform: scale(1.8);
      z-index: 99;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div className="row my-3 btn-group btn-group-toggle step-container mb-3" data-toggle="buttons">
        <div className="col p-0 my-auto">
            <label className="btn btn-radio mx-auto step active">
                <input type="radio" name="step" id="step1" autocomplete="off">1
            </label>
        </div>
        <div className="col p-0 my-auto">
            <label className="btn btn-radio mx-auto step">
                <input type="radio" name="step" id="step2" autocomplete="off">2
            </label>
        </div>
        <div className="col p-0 my-auto">
            <label className="btn btn-radio mx-auto step">
                <input type="radio" name="step" id="step2" autocomplete="off">3
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/piyush05/edhza4ts/1/
Check if this what you need...

Comment: @Piyush tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Is that fiddle giving you the desired output?

Comment: @Piyush not really, I tried removing +label but style doesn't change

Comment: It's being changed in the fiddle I added, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an function for the radio click which will remove the active class from already set active elements and add class to the current element. 
you can refer to the below example.

```js
function myFunction(e) {
     var arr = document.getElementsByName('radioa');
        arr.forEach(function(a) { a.classList.remove("active");});
       e.classList.add("active");
    }
```

```css
.active{
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000, 0px 0px 10px #fff, 0px 0px 10px #fff;
  transform: scale(1.8);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="myFunction(this)"/>
    <input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="myFunction(this)"/>
    <input type="radio" name="radioa" onclick="myFunction(this)"/>
```